# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/

Tags: tomcat, cors

I am using CORS and while sending rest call i am getting this "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "example.com:8080" error. On windows machine same call works across all browser but when I do it on Ubuntu I get this error no matter what ever browser I use.